# determine UIWebView height when web view content resized

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Am using `UIWebView` to load a widget in my view controller I want to adjust the frame when widget content size is changed.

My below code returns the original height when an option is selected twice

Here is my code

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    CGRect frame1 = _widget_VW.frame;
    frame1.size.height = 60;
    _widget_VW.frame = frame1;
    [_widget_VW sizeToFit];

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        NSLog(@"User tapped a link.");
        [_widget_VW sizeToFit];

        [_widget_VW setSuppressesIncrementalRendering:YES];

        CGRect frame = _widget_VW.frame;
        frame.size.height = 1;
        _widget_VW.frame = frame;
        CGSize fittingSize = [_widget_VW sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
        frame.size = fittingSize;
        _widget_VW.frame = frame;

        _VW_activity.hidden = NO;
        [_activityindicator startAnimating];
        [self performSelector:@selector(setup_DATA) withObject:_activityindicator afterDelay:0.01];

        return YES;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.
It worked for me.

```
#pragma mark - UIWebViewDelegate methods
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
    CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
}
```